# Why does: string st = "" + 12; work in c# without conversion?

Tags: c#, string

This is super dumb, but I've googled and checked references and I just cannot find an answer... Why can an int or float etc be added as part of a string without converstion but not on it's own? that is:

while this work fine:

```
 string st = "" + 12;
```

this doesn't (of course):

```
 string st = 12;
```

Where is the magic here? I know it works I just want to know WHY it works and how I control HOW the conversion is done?

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4472900/how-is-null-true-a-string

Comment: @Cybernate: I **knew** someone was going to link that :)

Comment: :).. Yep.. Its on my favorites list..

Comment: See the answer by `Jon Skeet` accepted by me on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4472900/how-is-null-true-a-string

Comment: This was alot more complicated then I expected but I now fully understand the reasons behind this (strange) behavior. I guess that you could call the + operator behavior of strings as "implicit conversion with an explicit feel" which was what amazed me the most, it seemed so explicit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first statement, the left operand for the `+` is a string, and as such `+` becomes the concatenation operator. The compiler finds the overload for that operator which takes a string and an arbitrary value as operands. This converts both operands to strings (using `ToString()`) then joins them.

The second statement does not work because there's no implicit cast from `int` to `string`.

You can control how the conversion is done by using parentheses to change the order of operations (semi-effective) or by writing code to handle the conversions pre-emptively.

Answer (score 1):

This is how string concatenation is designed to work, and as [BoltClock's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490354/why-does-string-st-12-work-in-c-without-conversion/4490372#4490372) noted, the compiler is using the `+` as the string concatenation operator. From the [C# Language Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx) on string concatenation, we find that:

> Any non-string argument is converted to its string representation by invoking the virtual `ToString` method inherited from type `object`.

Answer (score 1):

String concats in .NET ultimately resolve to calls to one of the overloads of the static  [String.Concat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.concat.aspx) methods. This is an optimization to reduce the number of temporary strings that would otherwise be created when mutliple concatenations occur in a single statement.

In short the reason this works is because a number of the String.Concat overloads will accept `object` in the argument list and since an int, float etc. are in essence objects they can be passed to the Concat overload that accepts one or more `object` parameters. Internally Concat of basically does a `.ToString()` on the incomming object therefore turning your `int` into it's string representation.

In your specific example

```
string st = "" + 12;
```

The compiler will reconize that the first string is empty and simply call the `String.Concat(object)` overload. Which will convert the integer 12 to a string and assign it to `st`.

This overload is called because the integer can be implicitly boxed to fit into the object type and therefore satisfy the method overload selection.

Answer (score 0):

Because the compiler will call `.ToString()` on all objects if one of the parameters is a string.

Answer (score 0):

This is working because of the operator overload of the operator + on the string datatype.

Answer (score 0):

Because the first is an expression and there C# makes an implicit conversion.

The second is an assignement with a static value, and the static value has no methods to be called.

As long as the value to be asigned is a variable or expression return there will be a toSting method to call.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the compiler translates the addition to a call to `String.Concat()`.

Internally, all operands are boxed (if necessary) and passed to the `String.Concat` method (which of course calls `ToString()` on all arguments).